# Filter data with R from csv file

Tags: r, excel, csv, sorting, filter

I have a csv file of Facebook data with around 190,000 rows. The column names are the following:

`comment_id, status_id, parent_id, comment_message, comment_author, comment_published, comment_likes, Positive, Negative, Sentiment`

I want to find out which `comment_author` who has the most comments (# of `comment_message`) and a `Sentiment > 0`.

Does anybody know how to apply this filter using R?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post.

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your data frame you can use `dplyr` package as follow:

```
df %>% group_by(comment_author,sentiment) %>%
       dplyr::summarize(total_number_comment=sum(comment_message)) %>%
       as.data.frame() %>%
       arrange(desc(total_number_comment)) %>%
       filter(sentiment>0)
```

I didn't understand what you really want to do with the `sentiment` variable (you need to provide an example for instance), but the grouping part is done

Comment: thank you so much for your fast help! the sentiment shows numbers from -5 to 5, where 0 is neutral. For example -5 means that the comment is very negative. 
I tried to use your suggested code, but I always get the error- message: Error in df %>% group_by(comment_author, Sentiment) %>% dplyr::summarize(total_number_comment = sum(comment_message)) %>%  : could not find function "%>%" 
Do you know what I did wrong? Do I have to add something to your code?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @lzed do you have the dplyr library installed? just use before your code library("dplyr")